# CGAL Uniform surface mesh generation

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, mesh, cgal

I am using the tutorial [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesher/Surface_mesher_2mesh_an_implicit_function_8cpp-example.html) to generate a mesh given an implicit function (an ellipsoid).

I have two questions:

1. Is there a method to relate the mesh generation parameters (`angular_bound`, `radius_bound`, and `distance_bound`) to the resulting number of vertices and/or faces of the resulting mesh?
2. Is there a method to ensure a uniform mesh over the surface? For example, this Matlab code offers a uniform mesh generation function [DistMesh](http://persson.berkeley.edu/distmesh/).

Thank you

Comment: What do you call a *uniform mesh* ?

Comment: Short answers: 1) no. 2) It depends.

Comment: From a quick reading of the paper associated with Distmesh states that a uniform mesh has all surface facets of equal area. I don't think this is implemented in CGAL as it requires iteration to adjust vertices to minimize a global function. But from an email on the cgal list there seems to be a way to get something similar by adjusting the inputs to the surface mesh creator.

Comment: @shaksk: usually, ensuring equal areas is a nightmare.